# Spring beans. Is it possible to return a default boolean if no bean exists

Tags: spring, return, boolean, javabeans, default

I have an interface which gets parameter values from a spring bean xml file.

The problem is that I need to have the get-method in classes where there will be no parameter to fetch. The bean exists but this particular parameter does not exist in the xml-file. In those cases I would like the interface method to return false.

I was looking at the annotation `@ReturnValue` which looked promising but seems to only be able to return a `String[]`, not a `boolean`.

This works for a `String[]` but I want to return false instead, is that possible?

```
@ReturnValue(defaultsTo = "")
String[] getMyvalue();
```

Best Regards / Jan

Comment: Not without changing the return type of the method.

Comment: I got a suggestion to do this:
    @ReturnValue(defaultsTo = "false")
    boolean getMyValue();
The compiler seems to like it too so i hope it works :)